# In ANDROID how to pass values to a background thread which has an open socket connection

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, handler

I am trying to pass keyboard values to an android client to push it to a server.

I am using threads, but don't want to run a new thread or call `socketconnect` each time. Instead, I want to run a single thread, open socket connection and then use the same thread and already opened socket to push some values to server from keyboard.

A runnable example with handler will work in my case but I don't know how to code it. `ASYNCTASKS` wont help as it would open connection again and again.

**My Connection class is**

```
class conThread implements Runnable {
    public Handler dataHandler  = new Handler() ;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);//}
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}


**and my button has got the below code to send values to the thread for passing on to the server **

public void dataSend(View view) {
        conThread con = new conThread();
        new Thread(con).start();
        con.dataHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                        Log.d("Client", "S: data");
                        out.print("3333");
                        out.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

I get connected to the server but get a crash after that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If at all possible show some code you have tried. How-to questions without showing your code may not get the best response.

Comment: thanks @bcperth see my code above please.